# I have added many photos from Camera to Album X for sorting. Is there any way to automatically add all remaining photos in Camera to Album Y?

Tags: file-management, automation, google-photos, google-pixel-2, folders

Album X is supposed to be a "best of" album. However, I keep on noticing very good photos that I previously missed, and am adding them to Album X in an ad-hoc manor. It would be better to add all photos not already in Album X to Album Y so that I can go through them again as a group and promote more to Album X as necessary. Is there a way to automate the process of adding the thousands of photos in Camera which are not already in Album X to Album Y?

NB, as an alternative to automatically adding all photos to Album Y which are not already in Album X: Is there a way to view all the photos in Camera alongside some kind of identifier of whether they are also in Album X? Even that would make the sorting process much easier.

Comment: I have a solution if you are happy to use windows tools, which doesnt involve copying all files down, just the ones you move, one at a time

Comment: @Rohit Gupta I may be happy to use Windows tools